# Is it possible to compare two complex plane contour integrals' absolute value?

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration, integral-inequality

In a real variable integral, it is true that $\oint f(x)dx\leq \oint g(x)dx$ if $|f(x)|\leq |g(x)|$ for all x. But i think the similar proposition doesn't hold for  the case of complex plane contour integral , $|\oint f(z)dz|\leq |\oint g(z)dz|$ if $|f(z)|\leq |g(z)|$ for all z .

My qusetion:
Is there any possible ways or conditions to compare two contour integral's absolute value? It doesn't have to be as clear as above inequality. I'm just wondering whether such a similar inequality exists.

Thank you for reading my qusetion and have a nice day!

Comment: It's not true for real variables either.  Counterexamples are very easy to find.

Comment: oh it might be f(x)<g(x) for all x. so there are no general size comparison method in complex contour integral?

Comment: the complex integral depends on both the modulus and of the argument so even if you have high modulus, if the argument varies, you can still get $0$ as for a holomorphic function and a closed curve; so in order to say something, you need to control the argument of $g$

Comment: The only inequality I've seen that looks remotely like this is: if $\varphi \colon [a, b] \to \mathbb{C}$ is a rectifiable path, of length $L(\varphi),$ with image $\varphi^* = \{\varphi(t) : a \leqslant t \leqslant b\},$ and $f$ and $g$ are integrable on $\varphi,$ then $$\left\lvert\int_\varphi f - \int_\varphi g\right\rvert \leqslant L(\varphi)\sup\{|f(z) - g(z)| : z \in \varphi^*\}.$$ See e.g. G. J. O. Jameson, *A First Course on Complex Functions* (1970), proposition 1.7.2.

Comment: Thank you all for your very helpful reply and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ and $g$ are analytic on $\mathbb C$ except for isolated singularities, and $|f(z)| \le |g(z)|$ whenever both are defined, then $\left|\int_C f(z)\; dz\right| \le \left|\int_C g(z)\; dz\right|$ for any path $C$ for which the integrals are defined.

The catch is that this is trivial.  The function $h(z) = f(z)/g(z)$ has only isolated singularities which are all removable, and after removing them you have a bounded analytic function, which must be a constant.  So $f(z) = c g(z)$ for some constant with $|c|\le 1$, and then $\int_C f(z)\; dz = c \int_C g(z)\; dz$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and example! But I cannot understand why $h(z)$'s singularities are all removable (because singularities of $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ might be different) and why $h(z)$ must be a constant. Could you tell me the reference or exact proof of the proposition "If f and g are analytic on C except for isolated singularities, and $|f(z)|≤|g(z)|$ whenever both are defined, then$∣∫_Cf(z)dz∣≤∣∫_Cg(z)dz∣$ for any path C for which the integrals are defined."?

Comment: Since $|h(z)| \le 1$ wherever it is defined, the singularities are all removable by [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem).  A bounded analytic function on $\mathbb C$ is constant by [Liouville[s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)).

Comment: Thanks to you, I understood it very well. I’m really grateful for your help.